# Problem with hibernate - persistent context

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have something like `Person`, and `Address` object(`Person` has an `Address` and other properties).

I update `Address` or other properties in one request. And in another request I'm searching through all persons. But sometimes I can see properties modified and sometimes I cannot.

Just making another request will return me either modified or unmodified properties.

Where's the mistake. I tried to flush everywhere, commit, but without any success. Any idea?

My mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="zet",name="phone_number")
public class PhoneNumber {  
    private String id;  
    private String number;  
    private Person person;
    private int status;
    ......

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade= { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                         CascadeType.REFRESH })      
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Column(name="num",unique=true,nullable=false)
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which application do you develop? Web or desktop? Do you use custom cache mechanism?

Comment: web application. and we have just 1st level cache - default I guess.

Comment: Please share also you mapping definition. Without details it is just guessing the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try to check directly in database that data has changed.
What also comes to my ming is the idea of swollowing the exception somewhere in you app. In that case you neither can see an error nor data is changed.

Comment: Data are changed in a db correctly. but the persistent context - different threads probably hold old stuff

Comment: Then it probably has nothing to do with Hibernate itself. There is some caching of the entity out of Hibernate.
Of course different threads will contain old data of you do not use Hibernate session longer than per request. hibernate session is meant to be used in context of unit of work that is usually one Hibernate session per one HTTP request.

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks a lot for your help it's very appreciated. There are caches of session for different databases,different connection providers. And different session was being closed finally.

Comment: Please either post your solution as answer and accept it or delete the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I got it, thanks a lot for your(Petr Kozelek) help it's very appreciated. There are caches of session for different databases,different connection providers. And different session was being closed finally.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a transaction issue. Are you using Spring as a transaction manager?

To make sure the change is persisted, use:

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public void persistMyChange(Bean myBean) {
     myBeanDao.save(myBean);
  }
```

Transactional is readOnly to false by default, but your service layer may be wrapped in a Transactional with readOnly to true.